# Facebook Android SDK Upgrade 3.x to 4.x

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x

In my App i have used the Facebook SDK 3.14. Now i made an upgrade to 4.4.0 and i have to initialize the AccessToken and Profile objects for users which were logged in.

```
if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()==null) {
        String tempAccessToken = Preferences.getPreference(_context, PREFERENCES_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN, null);
        if (tempAccessToken != null) {
            String tempUserID = Preferences.getPreference(_context, PREFERENCES_FACEBOOK_ID, null);
            AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(new AccessToken(tempAccessToken,_context.getString(_resourceAppID),tempUserID,null,null,null,null,null));
            Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
            Preferences.removePreference(_context, PREFERENCES_FACEBOOK_ID);
            Preferences.removePreference(_context,PREFERENCES_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        }
    }
```

To initialize it correctly i use the saved AccessToken and FacebookUserID. By some users the method Profile.getCurrentProfile() returns null after this process.

Has anyone an idea why this happens?

Comment: where is your `CallbackManager` ?Can you add some more code please?

Comment: Did you make it work? What was the solution? I am using Facebook Android SDK 3.6.0 and there are many apps deployed with this version in my Google Account? What steps do I need to follow in order to upgrade to the 4.x version? Please help..

Comment: Oh yeah thats tricky. You have to follow the upgrade guide "Upgrading the Android SDK from 3.x to 4.x" from facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

I suggest that you have one BaseActivity which implements the CallbackManager. Another helpful info is to implement the AccessToken Tracker. If you have any questions write me a pn.